# How to write a custom deleter that works with multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, memory, multiple-inheritance

I have a program which uses a custom allocator and deallocator to manage memory.  I've recently encountered a leak that has lead me down a huge rabbit hole that end with custom deleters being incapable of handling multiple inheritance.  In the code sample below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;
 
class Arena {};

void* operator new(std::size_t size, const Arena&) {
    auto ptr = malloc(size);
    cout << "new " << ptr << endl;
    return ptr;
}

void operator delete(void* ptr, const Arena&) {
    cout << "delete " << ptr << endl;
    free(ptr);
}

class A 
{
public: 
    virtual ~A() = default;
};
class B 
{
public: 
    virtual ~B() = default;
};
class AB : public A, public B
{ 
public:
    ~AB() override = default;
};

int main()
{
    B* ptr = new (Arena()) AB;
    ptr->~B();
    operator delete(ptr, Arena());

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
new 0x55e20c8a6eb0
delete 0x55e20c8a6eb8
free(): invalid pointer
```

Because the address of B is a vtable somewhere inside AB.  Using the builtin `delete ptr` function leads to the pointer being returned to it's original value and freed successfully. I've found some information about top_offset being used to address this [here](https://shaharmike.com/cpp/vtable-part3/), but this is implementation dependent.  So, is there a way to convert a pointer to B back into a pointer to AB without knowing anything about AB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
void* dptr = dynamic_cast<void*>(ptr);
ptr->~B();
operator delete(dptr, Arena());
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1h6sMPqnz)

Note you need to dynamic_cast *before* destroying the `B` object.

Without RTTI things get hairy. I assume that in your real code you need the identity of the arena object (otherwise it would be trivial to define member operators new/delete that just pull an arena out of thin air and redirect to global placement new/delete). You need to store this identity somewhere. Hmm, if we only could dynamically allocate some memory for it... wait a minute... we are allocating memory, we can store it there, just increase the size appropriately...

```
union AlignedArenaPtr {
  Arena* arena;
  std::max_align_t align;
};

struct Base { // inherit everything from this

    virtual ~Base() = default;

    void* operator new(std::size_t size, Arena *arena) {
        auto realPtr = (AlignedArenaPtr*)::operator new(size + 
            sizeof(AlignedArenaPtr), arena);
        realPtr->arena = arena;
        return realPtr + 1;
    }

    void operator delete(void* ptr) {
       auto realPtr = ((AlignedArenaPtr*)(ptr)) - 1;
       ::operator delete(realPtr, realPtr->arena);
    }

    void* operator new(std::size_t size) = delete; // just in case
};
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MocWbE6bK)

Comment: What does the dynamic_cast get you here over `void* dptr = ptr;`?

Comment: Yes that does work... but I also have no RTTI either.

Comment: @bpmckinnon Then you need to implement your own RTTI, or store the arena pointer in the object itself and use member `operator delete`.

Comment: @RyanHaining `dynamic_cast<void*>` returns a pointer to the most derived object. In other words, exactly "convert a pointer to B back into a pointer to AB without knowing anything about AB".

Comment: TIL for `dynamic_cast` ["If T is “pointer to cv void”, then the result is a pointer to the most derived object pointed to by v."](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.dynamic.cast#7)

Comment: I'm getting a warning about RTTI not being defined, but as far as I can tell it's not a valid warning in the specific case of dynamic_cast<void*>. Thanks!

Comment: I stand corrected.  On my visual studio 2022 build this raises an exception.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux there's not a lot of C++ I think I know thoroughly, but I really thought I knew how dynamic_cast worked